# Is there anyway to connect Java to React without having to use Spring?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, mongodb, morphia

So I have to build an offline project using MongoDB (with morphia), Java and React/Angular. I'm planning to work with react but all the solutions point to me using Spring Boot or Spring Data for this purpose. Is there no other framework that I could use to make this?

Its a very simple application where we need to list out some database entries and allow a user to make a request and change the entry values based on it.

I know Struts is also an option but remember that Im not actually going to deploy this online. This is like a show and tell to these lecturers on my own device.

**NOTE** I would have used Spring Data but as far as I know it doesnt have proper support for morphia? I could be wrong. Please let me know if it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are literally dozens of Java [micro]frameworks to chose from:

- [Vert.x](https://vertx.io)
- [Javalin](https://javalin.io)
- [Spark](http://sparkjava.com)
- [Micronaut](http://micronaut.io)
- [Ratpack](https://ratpack.io)
- [Dropwizard](https://www.dropwizard.io)
- [Ninja](http://www.ninjaframework.org)
- [Rapidoid](https://www.rapidoid.org)

... and many more.

You can also try [Play](https://www.playframework.com) or [Ktor](https://ktor.io) or [Grails](https://grails.org). Or do some hardcore with [Netty](https://netty.io) or [Undertow](http://undertow.io).

Not to mention plain old servlets...

Vert.x in particular supports reactive MongoDB drivers: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/java.